# Python FileStorage: Read XML file

Tags: python, opencv3.0

Below is a simple example to write an XML file and read it back. The writing works OK, but I am not sure how to read this file back? Below is some sample code. How do I get thse values from the XML file?

```
file1 = 'result1.xml'
fs = cv2.FileStorage(file1, cv2.FILE_STORAGE_WRITE)
fs.write('var1', 1)
fs.write('var2', 2)


fs = cv2.FileStorage(file1,cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
fn = fs.real
```

Answer (score 0):

`Python` in different versions has its own library to parse XML data.
Here is where you can find the documentation : [XML Library](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/xml.html)

You have to be careful when using it, as said in title of the webpage, this library is not safe if XML files aren't built properly.
Here is another useful website : [How to parse XML files using Python ?](https://www.guru99.com/manipulating-xml-with-python.html)